# Seamless loop using SoundPool

Tags: android, loops, media-player, soundpool

I want to loop this track using MediaPlayer, but it makes this weird glitch noise at the end, The track seemed to work fine in Audacity and it uses .OGG, I tried using SoundPool but I cant seem to that that to work.

```
SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    AssetFileDescriptor lfd =      this.getResourc es().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.dishwasherloop);
    //mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try
    {
        //mediaPlayer.setDataSource(lfd.getFileDescriptor(),lfd.getStartOffset(), lfd.getLength());
        //mediaPlayer.prepare();
        //mediaPlayer.start();

        int dish = pool.load(lfd,1);
        pool.play(dish,0.5f,0.5f,1,-1,1.0f);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener()
        {
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                          int status) {
                   loaded = true;
               }
         });
         int soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.dishwasherloop, 1);
         soundPool.play(soundID, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move:

```
soundPool.play(soundID, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1f);
```

into the onLoadComplete handler, otherwise the SoundPool will try to play the sound before it's actually loaded. So something like this:

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener()
{
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status)
    {
       loaded = true;
       soundPool.play(sampleId, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
});
```

Note: the `sampleId` passed to the onLoadComplete handler is the `soundId` loaded.

Also, within the SoundPool.play(...), you're setting the loop flag to 0, which means never loop. If you wish the sound to loop, this needs to be -1:

```
soundPool.play(sampleId, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, -1, 1f);
```

Hope that helps.